# TFS: How to convert an Automated test to standard/manual test

Tags: testing, tfs, microsoft-test-manager

Currently I have a bunch of automated tests that have steps that can be run manually.  The steps are things like press a button and verify that the view changes.  The test is marked as automated because once upon a time it was automated, but the test system is now defunct.

How do I change the test so I can run the test by hand following the steps like a standard test case (non-automated)?

I don't see a way to change it back to "Not Automated", or run it as not automated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Test Manager or in the TFS Test Run you can select `Run with options` to choose to test the old automated tests manually. The Run with options allows me to choose how to run the test and select a manual method rather than the automated one.

[image]

Select Run with Web Browser or with the Test Runner as part of the Test Manager:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Sorry that it's not able to convert an automated test into a manual test directly.

You have to manually copy and paste during the creation of a new test case.

For detailed steps refer to how to [Create manual test cases](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/create-test-cases?view=azure-devops).

Besides, if you just want to run these tests, do not mind manual or auto.

You could also try to associate automated tests with test cases, add the test cases to the test suite, and run VSTest to make `Select tests using` set to `Test Plan`.

[image]

[image]

The test cases in test run list with test cases name, not methods name.

[image]

Comment: Just another mistake of Microsoft.  I hope this is not the only answer, but with a username containing - MSFT, probably means there isn't another option.  Isn't there something I can do with the database or will these reside in completely different tables?

Comment: Afraid not. Besides it's not suggest to  dig into the TFS database directly and highly not recommend to modify the original  database data. Doing so invalidates any support you may receive from microsoft for that instance of TFS. Sorry for any inconvenience.

Comment: I think the actual solution is to use `Run with options` to choose to test the old automated tests manually.  The `Run with options` allows me to choose how to run the test and select a manual method rather than the automated one.